# Разбить картинку на части opencv

Tags: c++, изображения, opencv

Код падает на функции копирования с ошибкой доступа к памяти. Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить?

```
    //Create instance of image
    IplImage* part_1 = 0;
    IplImage* part_2 = 0;
    IplImage* src = 0;
    IplImage* image = 0;

    // получаем картинку
    src = cvLoadImage(path.c_str(), 1);

    namedWindow("Original", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    namedWindow("Part_1", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    namedWindow("Part_2", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);    

    // размер ROI
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int width = src->width / 2;
    int height = src->height / 2;
    int add = 200;

    cvShowImage("Original", part_1);
    // устанавливаем ROI
    cvSetImageROI(part_1, cvRect(x, y, width, height));
    // копируем изображение
    cvCopy(src, part_1);
    // сбрасываем ROI
    cvResetImageROI(part_1);
    // показываем изображение
    cvShowImage("Part_1", part_1);

    // устанавливаем ROI
    cvSetImageROI(src, cvRect(width, width, width, height));
    // копируем изображение
    cvCopy(src, part_2);
    // сбрасываем ROI
    cvResetImageROI(src);
    // показываем изображение
    cvShowImage("Part_2", part_2);

    // ждём нажатия клавиши
    cvWaitKey(0);
    // освобождаем ресурсы
    cvReleaseImage(&image);
    cvDestroyAllWindows();
    return 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
IplImage* part_1 = 0;
IplImage* part_2 = 0;
IplImage* src = 0;
IplImage* image = 0;
```

4 указателя на структуры, но в никуда.
хотя бы так:

```
IplImage* src = cvLoadImage(path.c_str(), 1);
IplImage* part_1 = cvCloneImage(src);
IplImage* part_2 = cvCloneImage(src);
IplImage* image = cvCloneImage(src);
```

тогда и память будет зарезервированна.
В конце не забыть освободить память всех 4. изображений:

```
cvReleaseImage(&src);
cvReleaseImage(&part_1);
```

...

Но вообще интерфейс чисто Си-шный и лучше использовать С++

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить эту строку вместо копирования:

```
part = cvCloneImage(src);
```

Comment: теперь падает на **cvSetImageROI(part_1, cvRect(x, y, width, height));**